# Como faço GroupHeader agrupando por mais de um field?

Tags: delphi, relatório, fast-reports

Estou fazendo um relatório no FastReport que retorna demostra os seguintes campos:

```
codigo cliente  
nome cliente  
data do atendimento  
codigo atendente  
nome Atendente  
codigo atendimento  
motivo do atendimento
```

E precisava agrupar os atendimentos pelo cliente/data/atendente mostrando os diversos atendimentos do cliente no mesmo dia realizado por um determinado atendente agrupados.

Contudo no `groupheader` do `fastreport` só permite selecionar um único campo(pelo menos do jeito que eu sei). Como faço pra agrupar por mais de um campo simultaneamente?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma alternativa simples é você criar um Field que é a concatenação das informações que você precisa agrupar. Por exemplo:

```
cast(Cliente || Data || Atendente as varchar(100)) as agrupa
```

Daí no groupheader você agrupa pelo field `agrupa`.

Answer (score 0):

Sim o `groupheader` do `FastReport` aceita apenas um único campo ou utilizar dependendo da construção de sua query o campo **Expression**.
[image: Agrupamento]

Em situações como esta realizo a utilização de três `groupheader` subsequente retirando o visible sobre os dois primeiros. Caso necessário realizo a impressão forçada do último com `Engine.ShowBand(NomeDoGroupHeader)`.

Answer (score 0):

No **fastreport** você pode agrupar por mais de um field utilizando a propriedade **Condition** da banda **GroupHeader** selecione a opção para informar uma Expressão nela você pode concatenar da seguinte maneira:

```
<frxDados."dado1">+<frxDados."Dado2">
```

Dessa forma o groupHeader vai agrupar pela concatenação dos filds informados.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).